# Aggregation in mongodb and group by 15 min

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a Schema in mongodb like:
INPUT

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5e05c1089b3e4e333cee8c39"),
  name:"Alex",
  activity:[
        {
            _id: ObjectId("5e05c1089b3e4e333cee8c39"),
            type: 'run',
            start_timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-11T11:34:59.804Z"),
            end_timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-11T11:40:00.804Z")
        },
        {
            _id: ObjectId("5e05c1089b3e4e333cee8c40"),
            type: 'stop',
            start_timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-11T11:40:00.804Z"),
            end_timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-11T11:42:00.804Z")
        },
        {
            _id: ObjectId("5e05c1089b3e4e333cee8c41"),
            type: 'wait',
            start_timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-11T11:42:00.804Z"),
            end_timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-11T11:52:00.804Z")
        },
        {
            _id: ObjectId("5e05c1089b3e4e333cee8c41"),
            type: 'stop',
            start_timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-11T11:52:00.804Z"),
            end_timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-11T12:02:00.804Z")
        },
        {
            _id: ObjectId("5e05c1089b3e4e333cee8c41"),
            type: 'sleep',
            start_timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-11T12:02:00.804Z"),
            end_timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-11T12:48:00.804Z")
        }
  ]
}
```

This is a schema for a man activity, i need to find brake-up of every 15 minute (brake-up duration in minute),i have found a solution stackoverflow but here only single timestamp but in my case there are 2 timestamp and first i have to calculate duration and then group by according to 15 minute

OUTPUT

```
[
  {
        _id: "2020-01-11T11:34 to 2020-01-11T11:49" ,
        duration: "15 min",
        "brake-up":{
          run:"6 min",
          stop:"2 min",
          wait:"7 min"
        }
   },
   {
        _id: "2020-01-11T11:49 to 2020-01-11T12:04" , 
        duration: 15 min,
        "brake-up":{
          wait:"3 min"
          stop:"10 min"
          sleep:"2 min"
        }
   {
        _id: "2020-01-11T12:04 to 2020-01-11T12:19" , 
        duration: 15 min,
        "brake-up":{
          sleep:"15 min"
        }
   }
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit *tedious* solution.

### Explanation

I assume `activity.type` not repeated inside `X` min break-up
I assume `start_timestamp` and `end_timestamp` `as is` (don't ignore seconds:milliseconds)

1. We calculate min / max dates from `start_timestamp` and `end_timestamp`
2. We calculate how many `15 min breaks` are between min / max dates
3. We create `from` and `to` variables that includes `X` min break-up from min / max dates
4. For each `from` and `to`, we filter activities
5. Once we filter, we calculate waste time taking in mind `from` and `to` and `start_timestamp` and `end_timestamp` dates
6. We create `Array` with activity + waste time and transform it into object

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      root: "$$ROOT",
      duration: {
        $toInt: 15
      },
      "start": {
        $reduce: {
          "input": "$activity",
          initialValue: ISODate("2100-01-01"),
          in: {
            $min: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.start_timestamp",
              "$$this.end_timestamp"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "end": {
        $reduce: {
          "input": "$activity",
          initialValue: ISODate("1970-01-01"),
          in: {
            $max: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.start_timestamp",
              "$$this.end_timestamp"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      interval: {
        $range: [
          0,
          {
            $round: {
              $divide: [
                {
                  $toLong: {
                    $subtract: [
                      "$end",
                      "$start"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  $multiply: [
                    "$duration",
                    60,
                    1000
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$interval"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      from: {
        $add: [
          "$start",
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$interval",
              {
                $multiply: [
                  "$duration",
                  60,
                  1000
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      to: {
        $min: [
          "$end",
          {
            $add: [
              "$start",
              {
                $multiply: [
                  {
                    $add: [
                      "$interval",
                      1
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $multiply: [
                      "$duration",
                      60,
                      1000
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      activity: "$root.activity"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      activity: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$activity",
          cond: {
            $or: [
              {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $gte: [
                      "$$this.start_timestamp",
                      "$from"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $lte: [
                      "$$this.end_timestamp",
                      "$to"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $lte: [
                      "$$this.start_timestamp",
                      "$to"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $gte: [
                      "$$this.end_timestamp",
                      "$from"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: {
        $concat: [
          {
            $toString: "$from"
          },
          " to ",
          {
            $toString: "$to"
          }
        ]
      },
      name: "$root.name",
      duration: {
        $concat: [
          {
            $toString: "$duration"
          },
          " min"
        ]
      },
      "brake-up": {
        $map: {
          input: "$activity",
          in: {
            k: "$$this.type",
            v: {
              $round: {
                $divide: [
                  {
                    "$subtract": [
                      {
                        $min: [
                          "$$this.end_timestamp",
                          "$to"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        $max: [
                          "$$this.start_timestamp",
                          "$from"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $multiply: [
                      60,
                      1000
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$brake-up"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        duration: "$duration",
        name: "$name",
        "brake-up-k": "$brake-up.k"
      },
      "brake-up-v": {
        $sum: "$brake-up.v"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id._id",
        duration: "$_id.duration",
        name: "$_id.name"
      },
      "brake-up": {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.brake-up-k",
          v: {
            $concat: [
              {
                $toString: "$brake-up-v"
              },
              " min"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      name: "$_id.name",
      duration: "$_id.duration",
      "brake-up": {
        $arrayToObject: "$brake-up"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IoXAYbqP1wb)

Comment: you are such a great person, i'm really thankful to you from bottom of my heart, i'm finding this solution in many forum from many days, finally found this great solution, once again thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome. I found it a headache, but interesting. No follow up is necessary, just keep sharing interesting problems. Good luck

Comment: i need some little help from your side, activity.type can be repeated  X min of break-up

Comment: Can I assume activities can be one of: run, stop, wait, sleep?

Comment: Yes, run can be twice between 15 min of duration

Comment: Done. Check it again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205799/discussion-between-codexxx-and-valijon).